# How to place an image on a specific page

Tags: media, theming, 7

I have created a page, `page-5`. I want to insert an image only on this page through .tpl.php not through the CMS itself. I have created an empty document `page--page-5.tpl.php`.
What content would go in there and how would I place my image?

For the front page, I was able to do with the following code:

```
<?php if (drupal_is_front_page()) {?>  
  <a class="join-btn" href="/node/38">
  <img src="/sites/all/themes/ypwb/images/joinb.png"></a> 
<?php }?>
```

How to do for a specific page?

Comment: For the front page i was able to do with the following code:                                                    <?php if (drupal_is_front_page())
    {?>
      <a class="join-btn" href="/node/38"><img  src="/sites/all/themes/ypwb/images/joinb.png"></a>
    <?php }?>
How to do for a specific page.

Comment: If you have created a tpl for the a specific page then it would only effect that page and not any other page. 

Dont have to do any conditional calls. And for front page it is better to use the page--front.tpl.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check [template suggestions](http://drupal.org/node/1089656) in the documentation.

> The list of suggested template files is in order of specificity based
>   on internal paths. One suggestion is made for every element of the
>   current path, though numeric elements are not carried to subsequent
>   suggestions. For example, "http://www.example.com/node/1/edit" would
>   result in the following suggestions:
>
> 1. page--node--edit.tpl.php
> 2. page--node--1.tpl.php
> 3. page--node.tpl.php
> 4. page.tpl.php

The template name started with "page--" is an override of [page.tpl.php](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!page.tpl.php/7) for a particular node or whatever.

- Find out what is the node ID of your "page-5", let's say it is node ID 1.
- Copy **page.tpl.php** and rename to **page--node--1.tpl.php**
- Then you can update it as you need ( print your image like you did in the front page ).